# Thevenin voltage calculation

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkHIHm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit is simplified like above to solve the thevenin voltage.The solution says that \$V_{AB} = 14 V\$. I couldn't understand that, i used Kirchhoff's Voltage Law using counter clockwise loop: \$V_A + 2V - 16 V = V_B\$ which is \$V_B - V_A = -14 V = V_{AB}\$. Could you tell me what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYsM5v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Kirchoff's Voltage Law gives : \$ V_{AB} = V_{A} - V_{B} = V_{AE} + V_{ED} + V_{DC} + V_{CB} \$

If we assume the circuit remains open, no current flows trough the resistors and we have \$ V_{AE} = V_{CB} = 0V \$ according to Ohm's Law.

Hence \$ V_{AB} = V_{ED} + V_{DC} = -2 + 16 = 14V \$.

Perhaps you got confused with the very definition of \$ V_{AB} = V_{A} - V_{B} \$

Comment: Thanks, you can add the equations with the latex rather than images.

Comment: @Gingerbread Thanks, I've modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> \$V_B−V_A =−14V = V_{AB}\$

This is wrong....

\$V_B−V_A  =  V_{BA}\$ , not \$V_{AB}\$

When we use the notation \$V_{AB} \$, it means the potential difference/voltage between A and B.

We expand it as \$V_A−V_B\$, not \$V_B−V_A\$.

And
\$V_{AB} = - V_{BA}\$

Answer (score 0):

\$V_{AB}\$ means the voltage measured from A to B, meaning that B is the "minus" probe of your volt-meter. 
Since the current is zero, the voltage must be the sum of the voltage sources.

The voltage sources have opposite direction so the answer is that the voltage is of the magnitude 14. If you reference from B to A it is -14, from A to B it is 14. 
What is "wrong", is the choice of reference.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage from A to B (Vab) implies the voltage at point A is greater than the voltage at point B. Since this is a series circuit, I tend to mentally add these dc voltage sources based on the their drawn polarity.  In this case, +16v +(-2v) =14v because my assumed current is in the clockwise direction. This gives me a new, single battery of 14v. Dividing the 14v by R1+R2 gives me I.  Now 14v-IR1 -Vab-IR2=0 and Vab can be solved for.  Note if the 2v battery were to become greater than 16v the direction of the current will change direction and Vab will change polarity